# Creating a cumulative objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, for-loop

I have one array of dates, and one array of objects. Each have a date property. I need to cumulatively sort the objects by date. So, for every date in the date array, I would like to create a cumulative object with every object who's date property is previous to the date in the date array.

**For example, the following date array and object array:**

```
['2017-11-5', '2018-3-1', '2018-3-22']

[{name: 'Jes', date: '2017-11-2'}, {name: 'Jill', date: '2018-1-5'}, {name: 'Joe', date: '2018-2-25'}, {name: 'Jack', date: '2018-3-21'}]
```

**The desired output would be:**

```
[{name: 'Jes', date: '2017-11-2'}]

[{name: 'Jes', date: '2017-11-2'}, {name: 'Jill', date: '2018-1-5'}, {name: 'Joe', date: '2018-2-25'}]

[{name: 'Jes', date: '2017-11-2'}, {name: 'Jill', date: '2018-1-5'}, {name: 'Joe', date: '2018-2-25'}, {name: 'Jack', date: '2018-3-21'}]
```

I am trying to do this with approximately 500 dates and 30,000 objects.

Here is a current code snippet, but I am having issues with performance, due to the number of objects I am iterating through.

```
    _.each(dtArray,function(i:Date){
  let dt = new Date(i);
  let filtered = _.filter(data,function(row){
    let dtVal = new Date(row['date']);
    return dtVal<=dt;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Joe, you are correct, I have corrected the desired result

Comment: If you are able to format your dates as YYYY-MM-DD, they will sort lexically and so be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the dates since you want one result array for each date. Then within the map you can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the people based on the date to create that array:

```js
let dates = ['2017-11-5', '2018-3-1', '2018-3-22']

let people = [{name: 'Jes', date: '2017-11-2'}, {name: 'Jill', date: '2018-1-5'}, {name: 'Joe', date: '2018-2-25'}, {name: 'Jack', date: '2018-3-21'}]

let cumul = dates.map(d => people.filter(person => person.date <= d))
console.log(JSON.stringify(cumul, null, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks mark! This creates the cumulative arrays i was looking for, but it only returns the date values, how can include the name property as well?

Comment: @user2821694 I'm seeing `name` when I run this snippet. You're not?

Comment: This will not work reliably as given `person.date <= d`, 2018-11-15 will sort as less than 2018-11-2. If the dates are changed to ISO 8601 format, then it will sort correctly.

Comment: You're right @RobG. It would be helpful if the dates were ISO 8601 (i.e. 2018-11-02)

Comment: @Mark Meyer, this solution did work for me however it did not improve the performance, it take 50-60 seconds for this to run when I use my real data set

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can improve your algorithm while keeping the associative indices in [image]:

- Precalculate date objects and only calculate them once for both `people` and `dates`
- Sort `dates` in an ascending manner
- Re-use precalculated/pre-filtered results, see [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)
- Save `dates` and `people` indices to keep the original order
- Swap items between `remaining` and `lastChunk` to reduce `remaining` size if `people[i].date < dates[j]`

The algorithm code:

```
function filter(dates, people){
    let lastChunk = [];
    let remaining = people;
    let results = [];
    // precalculate dates, preserve indexes and sort by date
    let sortedDates = dates
        .map((value, index) => {
            return {
                date: new Date(value),
                index: index
            };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
            return a.date<b.date?-1:a.date==b.date?0:1;
        });
    let peopleWithDates = people.map((value, index) => {
        value.dateObject = new Date(value.date);
        value.index = index;
        return value;
    });
    for(const i in sortedDates){
        const comp = sortedDates[i].date
        remaining = remaining.filter((value, index) => {
            if(value.dateObject<=comp){
                let itemIndex = value.index;
                delete value.dateObject;
                delete value.index;
                lastChunk.splice(itemIndex, 0, value);
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        });
        results[sortedDates[i].index] = [...lastChunk];
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: `new Date(value)` will result in an invalid date in Safari at least as the timestamps are not compliant with any of the formats specified in ECMA-262.

Comment: This could be solved like this: `const parseDate = date => new Date(date+"T00:00:00");` which result in parsing date in UTC format.

Comment: No, it can't. The problem is that "2018-3-1" is not consistent with ECMA-262 (or ISO 8601). If it was compliant, i.e. "2018-03-01", it should be parsed as UTC anyway. But that's irrelevant for the sake of sorting.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, missing the left padding.

Comment: This could be solved this way: `const parseDate = date => {
    const [year, month, day] = date.split("-");
    return new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, parseInt(day));
}`

Comment: A better alternative would be: `const parseDate = date => {
    const [year, month, day] = date.split("-");
    return parseInt(day)+parseInt(month)*31+parseInt(year)*31*12;
}`, as this would not construct any Date object.

Comment: I think it's very much simpler to just reformat the strings as ISO 8601 compliant and use the built–in sort. A clever regular expression should do the trick. Or `'2017-1-2'.split('-').map(s=>(s<10?'0':'')+s).join('-');`

Comment: @user2821694 why do you pretend you are blindly not seeing my answer?